# Laravel Different Views Folder

Tags: laravel, view, laravel-blade, laravel-resource

I have downloaded a project and I noticed that the project use views from different directory not the usual directory which are

```
\resources\views
```

but instead it create a new folder name **themes** and insert all the views in there.

```
\themes\app\views
```

[Views Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oibxl.png)

and also I noticed in the controller they return view by using getAppTheme()

[Return View using getAppTheme()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhKfG.png)

Anyone know how I can create a new folder outside the **\resources\views** folder for all my views file. And how I can return view using getAppTheme() just like in the picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks but the answer I was looking for is in here
https://github.com/Shipu/themevel
Anyway, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

there a config for view path at laravel located at config/views.php

you can configure there by change this

```
'paths' => [
    resource_path('views'), //this value you need to change
],
```